# tomcat no such method

Tags: java, tomcat

Getting this error .This runs on my local machine.
I need to know whether this is a tomcat version problem
And how to resolve it ?
Name of the jar is opencsv_2.4

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Ljava/util/List;
    at com.web.servlets.machinerypms.doPost(machinerypms.java:444)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: did you set tomcat lib folder path in classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have deployed the incorrect jar file. The servlet is attempting to invoke `parseRequest` from [this version of `ServletFileUpload`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html) but is finding [this one](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html) instead. The jar file can be found [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.2/commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar) or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

if you're using Maven

Comment: How do you read that exception? In other words, how do you know which method it is trying to invoke vs the method that it is actually finding? I am running into a similar problem, but not sure how to proceed.